# Cant rip CD in Rhythmbox

Tags: 14.10, rhythmbox, cd, gstreamer, ogg-vorbis

I'm trying to rip a CD in Ogg format, however it tells me that I'm missing: GStreamer element audioresample

It tries to download it but fails, does anybody know how to get this missing piece of software?

[image: Music preferences]

Answer (score 0):

The gstreamer element [audioresample](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-audioresample.html) is part of the base-plugins for the gstreamer packages.

This should be installed by default.

If you have deliberately decided to restrict the number of packages in your install or you have other packaging issues, audioresample should be provided by:

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base
```